# Parse JSON from website with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, json, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse a specific JSON object that can be found within a webpage's HTML code. I understand I have to use HtmlAgilityPack to essentially "trim out" the JSON from the rest of the HTML and I've used HtmlAgilityPack before, so I had an idea of what I needed to do.

My problem comes in where the specific JSON I'm looking for is in a script tag that contains multiple other JSON objects.

Here's a simplified version of what I get from the website:

```html
<script>
    window.website = {};
    window.website.STATE_FROM_SERVER = { big json here };
    window.digitalData = { big json here };
    window.extraState= = {};
</script>
```

The JSON object that I specifically want to extract and parse is the one under the `window.website.STATE_FROM_SERVER` tag. I've tried a snippet of code that I found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808337/parse-webpage-using-htmlagilitypack-and-json) question but it still returns the JSONs from all of those `window` tags.

Here's the snippet that I used:

```cs
var WebJson = WebpageHtml.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//script[contains(.,'window.website.STATE_FROM_SERVER')]");
```

This snippet would work if I only had to deal with 1 `window` tag, but there's 4 in this case and like I mentioned earlier, this returns all of the JSONs.

My question is, how can I retrieve the JSON object under the specific `window` tag that I'm looking for?

Comment: You can't parse JavaScript with HtmlAgilityPack.  You can use it to extract the embedded script but will need to use a JavaScript parser like [tag:jint] or [tag:jurassic] or `IActiveScriptParse32` to parse the embedded script.  Or I suppose a regex would also be an option.  See: [Parsing HTML to get script variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18156795), [Parsing javascript HTML using HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15296613), [parse and execute JS by C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4744105) or [Embedding JavaScript engine into .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/172753).

Comment: In fact this might be a duplicate of those questions, agree?